# Authentication fails when accessing CRUD routes via Postman and httpie

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication, postman, stormpath

I am using express-stormpath to handle user management in my express app. I am using stormpath's default login view and methods, requiring just email and password. I don't know if the problem is actually due to stormpath, however. When testing some CRUD routes, I am sure I am entering the correct credentials, yet authentication fails. Well, it doesn't fail outright; I get status 200 or 302 and am redirected back to the login page.

The command I am using with httpie is:

`http --verbose -a username@email.com:password localhost:3000/api/users`

The output from the above httpie command is:
[image]

For Postman (Chrome REST client) I'm using the Basic Auth helper.
[image]

Logging into the app via a web client works, however.

What is going on?

### Edit 1

This is how I have been protecting the routes:

`app.use('/', stormpath.loginRequired, routes);`

`app.use('/api/users', stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired, users);`

Comment: I assume it's not causing your problem, but the username you're showing in Postman is different from the one you're showing on the command line.

Comment: Neither are my actual username; I didn't use my actual username for privacy reasons. Sorry for the confusion. I changed the httpie command.

Answer (score 0):

I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), and I should be able to help out.  Could you show us how you're protecting the `/api/users` route?  You'll need to be using `stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired` middleware if you want to use Basic authentication.

Comment: I've edited my post. I have been using that middleware on `/api` routes but just `stormpath.loginRequired` on other routes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this library -- just wanted to chime in.

The issue here is that you're authenticating with your username and password -- this is NOT how our API authentication works.

What you need to do is create an API key for your user account first, then use that to authenticate.

Here's an example of how to create an API key for a user account:

```
req.user.createApiKey(function(err, key) {
  res.send('New API key created: id=' + key.id + ' secret=' + key.secret);
});
```

This will provision a new API key for your user, and output it.

Once you have the API key (it's in two parts, and ID and a secret), you can then make a request like:

```
http --verbose -a apikeyid:apikeysecret localhost:3000/api/users
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Thanks rdegges, for replying. There exists a problem even before API authentication, and that is login or user authentication. I removed the the `stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired` middleware from all my routes. I left in `stormpath.loginRequired` because I need it for CRUD operations among other things. The problem in the OP occurs even when I try to access `localhost:3000/`.

Comment: Even for `loginRequired`, you NEED to login using the web browser (it won't work with cURL). This is because of the way our CSRF protection works.